# Regex match HTTP request first line to groups

Tags: java, regex

I'm facing a scenario where I can get two kinds of HTTP requests:
With parameters, or without.

```
1. GET /index.html?x=1&y=2 HTTP/1.1
2. GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

I'd like to divide these two lines to regex groups.
I've got this regex string:

```
^(.+?)\s(\/.*)|((\/.*\?)(.+=.+)+)\sHTTP\/\d\.\d$
```

It's easier for your to see this here:
https://regex101.com/r/rH4rL1/5

As you can see, I'm trying to have a group for each set of parameters (x=1 is one group and y=2 is another groups).

Yet, as you can see in regex101, the whole line after the 'GET' is captured to a single group.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Offhand, it looks like this regex would do a lot of backtracking. You probably want to rein it in more and keep it on track; match the `GET`, then eat the domain until you get to, say `[/?\s]`.

Comment: After asking a question, it's a good idea to stick around for a little while and check for replies. *Ciao*.

Comment: Tom Zych, I'm using Java

Comment: `^(.+?)\s(\/.*)` matches both strings. The second alternative never comes into play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I should say that Java or any other mature language probably
has a facility to do this already, without having to roll your own.
Googling for `java parse http get request` turns up some prospects. For
the rest of this posting, I'll assume you want to roll your own for
whatever reason.

Okay, so it looks like you want to capture several things in groups.
Pathname first, protocol last, and any query strings in between. It
looks like the existing regex would also capture `GET`, but that's
constant so I won't bother. You can add it it you really want it.

```
GET /index.html?x=1&y=2 HTTP/1.1
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

In English:

- Match GET and whitespace
- Match and capture pathname until we hit `?` or whitespace
- Optionally match `?` and then capture any query strings until we hit whitespace
- Match and capture protocol

I don't know Java. This regex works in Python3. You should be able to
translate without too much trouble.

```
GET\s+([^?\s]+)((?:[?&][^&\s]+)*)\s+(HTTP/.*)
```

Note the second part, `((?:[?&][^&\s]+)*)`. The outer parentheses are
capturing and they capture the entire set of query strings, which must
later be split up at the ampersands. The inner parentheses use `?:`, an
extension that causes them to be non-capturing. I don't know if Java has
something similar. If there are no query strings, the middle item is an
empty string.

Comment: What if I wanted to convert these groups to Named Groups?

Comment: @johni In Java? How would I know?